# Creating multiple smaller 4x4 matrices from a larger 576x4 matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

So I am working with residential life to work on room assignments this year. So, I was given a massive excel file with all the information.

My job is to add three more columns [name of three roommates] in each row [student name]. I already did that using the CONCATENATE function in excel.

I was to verify that all my room assignments are correct. Following is what the data looks like for roommates named Joe, Moe, Poe, Zoe:

```
Student Name        Roomate1      Roommate 2     Roomate 3
Joe                 Moe           Poe            Zoe
Moe                 Poe           Zoe            Joe
Poe                 Zoe           Joe            Moe
Zoe                 Joe           Moe            Poe
```

What I found is that to ensure that the assignment is correct, I can just compare the matrix to its transpose and they both must be the same because of how the names are arranged.

So, **coming to the question**:

If I have a larger matrix of 4 x 576, how would I go about creating multiple smaller 4 x 4 matrices so I can perform the operation of checking on whether each smaller matrix is *equal* to its transpose.

Following is what I have to import the file and clean the data.

```
#Reading data frame from file from .csv file
RoommateCheck <- read.csv("RoommateCheck.csv", header = TRUE)

#Converting Data Frame to Matrix
RoommateCheckMatrix <- as.matrix(RoommateCheck)

#Taking out useless data
RoommateCheckMatrix <- RoommateCheckMatrix[2:617,6:9]  

#Comparing the smaller matrices to their transposes
RoommateGroup == t(RoommateGroup)
```

I tried creating two vectors which I could use to traverse through the larger matrix

```
x <- c(1 + 4 *(0:144))
y <- c(4 *(1:144))

for (i in x)
{
  for (j in y)
  {
    TempMatrix <- ResLifeNames[x:y,]
  }
}
```

but I kept getting the warning:

```
 Warning messages:
 1: In x:y : numerical expression has 145 elements: only the first used  
 2: In x:y : numerical expression has 144 elements: only the first used
```

which I have no idea to fix. My intention was to have two sequences of number which could be used as the variables to limit the rows which are to be transferred to the Temp matrix.

I looked through the description of each of the **apply** functions and couldn't find one that could  be used in this situation.

Comment: You want to use i and j rather than x and y: `ResLifeNames[i:j,]`. Although I'd suggest you check out the `seq` function which will save you the trouble of creating x and y in the first place.

Comment: Hahaha! Thank you. I knew it was a stupid mistake. But let me try doing using 'seq'. Also, I just realized that my for loop doesn't really work. Because I want the pairs [1,4] , [5,8], [9,12] to be be used. The foor loop goes for [1,4], [1,8], [1,12]... [5,4], [5, 8].

Answer (score 0):

Read in the data in the question using `as.is = TRUE` to keep it as character data and expand it to an 8x4 matrix `m` so we have a bit more to test with.

Let `k` be the number of 4x4 matrices.  In the example data `k` is 2.
Convert kx4 matrix `m` to a 4xkx4 array `a` such that `a[,1,]` is the first 4x4 matrix, `a[,2,]` is the second and if `m` were larger this would continue on.  Now `apply` over the 4x4 slices giving a logical vector of length `k`, `is.sym`, whose ith component is TRUE or FALSE as the corresponding 4x4 matrix is symmetric or not.  `all(is.sym)` will be a scalar that is TRUE if all 4x4 matrices are symmetric.

```
# create 8x4 test matrix
Lines <- "StudentName        Roomate1      Roommate2     Roomate3
Joe                 Moe           Poe            Zoe
Moe                 Poe           Zoe            Joe
Poe                 Zoe           Joe            Moe
Zoe                 Joe           Moe            Poe"   
RoommateCheck <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
m <- as.matrix(RoommateCheck)
m <- rbind(m, m)

# reshape into array and apply function over 4x4 slices
k <- nrow(m) / 4
a <- array(m, c(4, k, 4))
is.sym <- apply(a, 2, function(x) identical(x, t(x)))
all(is.sym)
```